# Gradle/Hibernate/Maven Annotations Foreign Key Creation

Tags: mysql, hibernate, gradle

I am currently working on a Gradle project that uses Maven/Hibernate. The program plugs-in to a MySQL database. I am generating the tables via the Java class. IE when I run it the first time it creates the tables.

My issue is that I am currently receiving this error "(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")". I am convinced it has to do with my annotations relating Staff and Tickets.

Staff class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Staff")
public class Staff implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int staffId;
private String badgeCode;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String skillLevel;
private String status;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticketId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Ticket> tickets;
```

Ticket Class:

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Ticket")
public class Ticket implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int ticketId;
private int customerId; 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "STAFF_ID")
private Staff helpStaff;
private String problemDesc;
private String resolution;
//(year, month, date, hrs, min, sec)
private Date createdDate;
private Date resolvedDate;
private String status;
```

So a Ticket has one Staff tied to it, which in my mind means ManyToOne. Whereas a Staff has many tickets, which is OneToMany. I was originally able to get the findAll() hibernate query to work, but it was returning the object ID for the Ticket field rather than any information about the ticket.

My questions are: What is causing the foreign key issue. Why is a tickets field not being created in the Staff table for the List and what is causing the object id to be returned rather than any real data?

Answer (score 0):

Answer given to me via another source. User g051051 on Reddit helped me out.

In the Staff class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="helpStaff", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Ticket> tickets;
```

In the Ticket class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="staffId", nullable=false)
public Staff getHelpStaff() { return helpStaff; }
```

So the list of Tickets will be determined by the helpStaff property of the Ticket class. The Ticket class will create an association column called staffId that will use the primary key of the Staff entity.